# Backbone.js: model.isNew() == true, but model.save() causes POST request instead of PUT

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

This is simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/2YE29/3/

What I'm doing wrong?

SOLVED: All right, i'm confused by this [article](http://www.slideshare.net/oisin/simple-rest-services-with-sinatra) (page 8). POST is right for CREATE in Backbone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found nothing wrong with your code. model.isNew() returns true mean your record hasn't been created yet, so POST request is sent. However, if the model.isNew() returns false, mean your model/record already exist, so PUT request will be sent.

Answer (score 2):

If you read [the documentation](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Sync) this is the expected behaviour.

> > The default sync handler maps CRUD to REST like so:
> >
> > **create → POST   /collection**
> >
> > update → PUT   /collection/id